# É possível colocar labels em ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Eu tenho várias `ListView`'s que uso para navegação, e coloquei como conteúdo `id's`.

Então, uma lista que deveria apresentar nomes de países, está apresentando o id dos países.

Existe algum modo de manter esses `id's` na lista mas exibir o nome para os usuários?

Eu preciso manter os ids para fazer as pesquisas no banco.

Comment: Coloca seu código pra ter uma ideia de como você está fazendo, e sim é possivel colocar o label, dentro do seu adapter você pode fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisará de um `Adapter` que herde de `BaseAdapter`. Isso irá te possibilitar que seu `Adapter` aceite outros objetos.

Para isso, você ira precisar criar um modelo `Pais` que tenha como atributo o seu `id` e o `nome` do país e passar para o seu `Adapter` e, por fim, definir este `Adapter` para o seu `ListView`.

Tente algo assim:

**Pais**:

```
public class Pais {
    private final int id;
    private final String nome;

    public Pais(int id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

**item_pais.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_nome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MeuAdapter**:

```
public class MeuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<Pais> paises;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    MeuAdapter(List<Pais> paises, Context context) {
        this.paises = paises;
        //LayoutInflater para inflar o seu Layout
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return paises.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return paises.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pais, null);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nome);
        }

        //Recupeando o seu pais de acordo com a posição
        Pais pais = paises.get(position);

        //Definindo o texto do item da sua linha
        holder.tvNome.setText(pais.getNome());

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvNome;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Pais> paises = new ArrayList<>();
        paises.add(new Pais(0, "Brasil"));
        paises.add(new Pais(1, "Argentina"));
        paises.add(new Pais(2, "Portugal"));

        MeuAdapter meuAdapter = new MeuAdapter(paises, this);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sua_list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(meuAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Pais pais = (Pais) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                //Recuperando o ID do país.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(pais.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem sim, para esse caso a solução são os `Adapter`. A maioria dos componentes visuais são projetados no padrão MVC (acho que é muito conhecido no ambiente web).

Bem, a `ListView` tem um modelo (que é um conjunto de dados internos), esse conjunto de dados pode ser "injetado" através de um `Adapter` que nada mais é do que o comportamento para renderizar a `View`.

[Documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sem o código fica um pouco complicado, mas imagino que você esteja preenchendo a `ListView` usando um `CursorAdapter`, certo? 
(Deve ser parecido com o que eu fiz [aqui](https://github.com/mariovalney/WebSMS/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/jangal/websms/ListSmsAdapter.java) )

Se for o caso, no método [`bindView()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#bindView(android.view.View,%20android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor)) é quando você "seta" o texto, nesse caso, não use o ID. Crie um método para receber o ID e retornar o nome do país.